# Symfony2 Error retrieving parameter within .yml

Tags: symfony, sonata

When I try to use a **parameter** defined in config.yml as the value of `sonata_seo.page.metas.property.fb: app_id` I get an error. If this same parameter is used as the value of `sonata_seo.page.title` everything works as expected.

### Steps to reproduce

app/config/config.yml

```
parameters:
    facebook_app_id: 1234567890    
sonata_seo:
    encoding:   UTF-8
    page:
        default:    sonata.seo.page.default
        title:      "%facebook_app_id%" # here receive correctly
        metas:
            property:
                # Facebook application settings
                "fb:app_id":          "%facebook_app_id%" # here broke the code
```

### Expected results

I expect this HTML tags render:

```
<title>1234567890</title>     
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890" />
```

### Actual results

```bash
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

the result is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Sonata\SeoBundle\Seo\SeoPage::addMeta() must be of the type array, null given, called in .../vendor/sonata-project/seo-bundle/Seo/SeoPage.php on line 146 and defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

app/config/config.yml

```yml
parameters:
    facebook_app_id: "1234567890"
```